# TYPO3 4.5: Upgrade to new version - at once or incremental?

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

Upgrading a neglected TYPO3 from 4.5 to hopefully newest version - wondering if anyone has done anything similar - if I need to go incrementally from major version to major version or if I can go from say 4.5 to 6.2, then to 10.x or something of that nature. Not sure how major the backend changes are from version to version.

Comment: Depending on how big the site is you should consider setting up TYPO3 10 from scratch and only copying parts like HTML Templates (convert to fluid) and css. If you have a small amount of pages that might be less work than an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to upgrade to 6.2, then 7.6. It's important to run the upgrade wizards in the install tool of each major version (6.2 and 7.6) to get your database updated properly.

After the upgrade to 7.6 I'd use [EXT:core_upgrader](https://github.com/IchHabRecht/core_upgrader/) on the command line to upgrade to 10.4 in one step.